# Catch is not a function

Tags: angular

I've just upgraded to Angular 10 and it works fine during `ng serve`. It also allows me to build without any errors however when I put the files up on a server it errors and just gives me the following message:

```
ERROR TypeError: t.handle(...).do(...).catch is not a function
```

This isn't really much to go off. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. I.e. What is `t` among other things

Comment: I'm guessing this is rxjs, in which case `do` is deprecated in favour of [`pipe(tap())`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do)

Comment: @Liam thank you so much, Very few articles are available on this issue.

Comment: Really?! https://www.learnrxjs.io/